# Parsing and modifying csv with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell but I've given it my best go.Have a .csv file, small example:

```
id,location_id,name,title,email,directorate 
1,1, Amy lee,Singer,, 
2,2,brad Pitt,Actor,,Production 
3,5,Steven Spielberg,Producer,spielberg@my.com,Production
```

Need to:

- change first and last name to uppercase, example, Brad Pitt, Amy Lee.
- create email with pattern first letter of first name + last name, all in lowercase with @google.com and value from location_id, example - alee1@google.com, bpitt2@google.com
- save it to new file.csv, with the same structure, example:

```
id,location_id,name,title,email,directorate 
1,1, Amy Lee,Singer,alee1@google.com, 
2,2,Brad Pitt,Actor,bpitt@google.com,Production 
3,5,Steven Spielberg,Producer,sspielberg@google.com,Production
```

I wrote a script, whose commands one by one perform the task, but dunno how to save it no new .csv file:

```
param (
    [string] $file_path
)

$inputFile = Import-Csv -Path $file_path

foreach ($line in $inputFile) {
    $line.name = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($line.name)
    $firstName = $line.name.split(" ")[0]
    $lastName = $line.name.split(" ")[1]
    $newEmail = ($firstName[0] + $lastName + $line.location_id + "@google.com").toLower()
}
```

Perhaps, there is more clean solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close to completion but here is a simpler way. You're already using [`TextInfo.ToTitleCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=net-6.0) but for the email address you could simplify it using the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator) operator and a bit of regex.

You can find info about the regex pattern in this link: https://regex101.com/r/WKF9R5/1

```bash
$txtInfo = [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture.TextInfo
$csv = Import-Csv path\to\csv.csv

foreach($line in $csv) {
    $name = $line.name

    $line.name  = $txtInfo.ToTitleCase($name)
    # Example: 'brad Pitt' => bPitt
    $line.email = ($name -replace '(?<=^\w{1})\w+\s').ToLower() + $line.location_id + '@google.com'
}

$csv | Export-Csv path\to\newcsv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Final output using the Csv in the question:

```
id location_id name             title    email                  directorate
-- ----------- ----             -----    -----                  -----------
1  1           Amy Lee          Singer   alee1@google.com
2  2           Brad Pitt        Actor    bpitt2@google.com      Production
3  5           Steven Spielberg Producer sspielberg5@google.com Production
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I ask you, to explain what’s going on in a first line of script?

Comment: @lunnyj the `cultureinfo` one? It's just the same as `Get-Culture`

Comment: can you help me again?:) how I can save new file  in the same directory where old file was located? Run my script, ./my_script.ps1 file.csv which located at the same directory where file.csv stored. But when I run script from the another directory, new file save in directory when the script located, but I need to save it on the same directory, where file.csv stored.